# Unable to identify the element using xpath in selenium

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

I have a element in the screen which has the following html:

```
<h4 class='font-bold'>
 "Reassignment from owner - job created 'Mr. User 221A'"
</h4>
```

**Case1:**
I'm creating below xpath which is then highlighting the element correctly in the screen:

```
//h4[text()="Reassignment from owner - job created 'Mr. User 221A'"]
```

**Case2:**
But in my code when I am creating the xpath below then it is not able to identify the element:

```
public clickArrowIcon(String cert,String username){
String element="//h4[text()='"+cert+" - job created "+username+"']
}

where cert=Reassignment from owner
      username ='Mr. User 221A'
```

It seems to me that due to quotes present in username that is creating the problem as the output that is coming for case2 xpath is --//h4[text()='Reassignment from owner - job created 'Mr. User 221A'']`

Answer (score 0):

Try to use contains() function of xpath, like that:

```
//h4[contains(text(),"Reassignment from owner - job created \'Mr. User 221A\'")]
```

have you tried to escape quotes with backslash, like that?

```
//h4[text()="Reassignment from owner - job created \'Mr. User 221A\'"]
```

or if it doesn't help, you can use and feature of xpath:

```
//h4[contains(text(),"Reassignment from owner - job created") and contains(text(),"Mr. User 221A")]
```